# Fall Over On His Side/Back

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I am confused about the following:

> 1. He fell on his side/back.
> 2. He fell **over** on his side/back.

I definitely found both versions on google.  Could the second version have redundancy with "over", because if a person has fallen in such a way that he ends up on his side/back, he must definitely have ***fallen over***?

Answer (score 1):

*Fall over* is a single term, not just the verb fall with an adverb modifying it. A person, structure, or object falls over when it falls from an upright position to a prone or lying one. A person thrown from a window simply falls, but if he trips on his shoelaces, he may fall over. A building that's dynamited to collapse inward just falls, but if it tips forward like [these buildings in China](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/asia/china/5685963/Nine-held-over-Shanghai-building-collapse.html), it falls over.

Both "fell on his side" and "fell over on his side" are grammatical, but *fell over* rules out some kinds of falling.

Comment: Could it be that "*fall over*" requires continuous contact (pivot point) with the ground?